# Probability density functions

Tags: distributions, density-function

The probability density function of $X$ is defined by:

\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
 \alpha     &  \quad,   0 \le x \le 1 \\
 \beta(x-4)^2 & \quad, 1 \le x \le 4
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Show that the exact values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{18}$ respectively:

We know that the total area under the probability density function is equal to $1$. But using this fact only gives us $\alpha + 9\beta = 1$.

Are there any other conditions that would give us another simultaneous equation, or allow us to conclude either $9\beta = 0.5$ or $\alpha = 0.5$ or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both intervals you have $x=1$ included, the two expressions for the two intervals *must* be equal at $x=1$. Left boundary is $\alpha$, and right boundary is $\beta(x-4)^2|_{x=1}=9\beta$. So, we have another equality: $\alpha=9\beta$.
Solving for the two, i.e. $\alpha=9\beta, \alpha+9\beta=1$ leaves us with solution $\alpha=1/2, \beta=1/18$.

Comment: What do you mean by the boundary points, as in x = 1 is the median?

Comment: No, I clarified the expression. Since both left interval and right interval intersect at $x=1$, the two functions defined in these intervals must yield the same value at their boundary, i.e. $x=1$. I mean what would you say if asked you $f(1)$? Is it $\alpha$ or $\beta(x-4)^2$? For the function to have only one value at $x=1$, the two must be equal.

Comment: Could they not be continuous though? So you can't have two possible values at x = 1?

Comment: PDF may be discontinuous, but it is a function and it cannot have two values for a specific $x$. If your question was for $0\leq x < 1$ and $1\leq x \leq 4$, we couldn't say anything, because $x=1$ isn't included in the first interval. But, since it's included, both right and left functions must yield the same value.